# Magento 2: Hide tier price element

Tags: magento2, configurable-product, pricing, tiered-pricing, visibility

Custom theme using Magento 2.2.1 in developer mode, inheriting from the `Magento/blank` theme.

When selecting an item from a sizing dropdown on a product page, created using a configurable product, an element appears, which I believe is the 'tier price'.

The element in question is`<div class="price-box price-tier_price" data-role="priceBox"></div>`.

I have tried adding `<referenceBlock name="price-tier_price" remove="true" />` and `<referenceBlock name="price-box" remove="true" />` to default.xml, but neither have worked.

Please can someone advise me how to hide this element?

Thanks.

**EDIT:**

Found this [link](https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/4945).
Looks like this might be the root of the problem, which is marked 'Done' ready for Magento 2.3.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Did a little reading up on Khoa TruongDinh's answer and discovered this issue posted on Magento's github:

> https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/4945

Looks like this is a known bug that has been fixed for v2.3.

I've managed to work around the bug in my custom theme using three different methods.

### Method One:

Added the line

> `<referenceBlock name="product.price.tier" remove="true" />`

to

> `<Vendor>/<Theme>/Magento_Theme/layout/default.xml`

and it seems to be working.

### Method Two:

First, I copied the file

> `Magento/Catalog/layout/catalog_product_view.xml`

to

> `<Vendor>/<Theme>/Magento_Catalog/layout/catalog_product_view.xml`

.

Then, I removed the following code from the new file:

```
<block class="Magento\Catalog\Pricing\Render" name="product.price.tier" after="product.info.price">
<arguments>
<argument name="price_render" xsi:type="string">product.price.render.default</argument>
<argument name="price_type_code" xsi:type="string">tier_price</argument>
<argument name="zone" xsi:type="string">item_view</argument>
</arguments>
</block>
```

### Method 3 (from Khoa TruongDinh's answer):

See how tier price is rendered:

> \Magento\ConfigurableProduct\Block\Product\View\Type\Configurable::getOptionPrices

Configurable product JS comes from here:

> Magento_ConfigurableProduct/js/configurable

Create `requirejs-config.js` file here:

> app/code/[Vendor]/[Module]/view/frontend/requirejs-config.js

Create the following mixin inside the file `requirejs-config.js`:

```
var config = {
    config: {
        mixins: {
            'Magento_ConfigurableProduct/js/configurable': {
                'Vendor_Catalog/js/configurable-mixin': true
            }
        }
    }
};
```

Then create `configurable-mixin.js` here:

> app/code/[Vendor]/[Module]/view/frontend/web/js/configurable-mixin.js

`configurable-mixin.js` should contain the following code:

```
define(
[
    'jquery'
],
function ($) {
    'use strict';

    return function (target) {
        $.widget('mage.configurable', target, {

            _displayTierPriceBlock: function (optionId) {
               //Do no thing here.
            }
        });

        return $.mage.configurable;
    };
});
```

### Method 4 (from goodlook's answer):

Copy the file

> `Magento/Catalog/layout/catalog_product_view.xml`

to

> `<Vendor>/<Theme>/Magento_Catalog/layout/catalog_product_view.xml`

and remove the following line:

```
<?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ $block->renderAmountMinimal() ?>
```

Answer (score 3):

We can see how tier price was rendered: `\Magento\ConfigurableProduct\Block\Product\View\Type\Configurable::getOptionPrices`.

There is an easy way to hide the tier price - but not sure it's the best way:

The js for changing value of configurable product comes from `Magento_ConfigurableProduct/js/configurable`.

We need to override it by using mixin

app/code/[Vendor]/[Module]/view/frontend/requirejs-config.js

```
var config = {
    config: {
        mixins: {
            'Magento_ConfigurableProduct/js/configurable': {
                'Vendor_Catalog/js/configurable-mixin': true
            }
        }
    }
};
```

app/code/[Vendor]/[Module]/view/frontend/web/js/configurable-mixin.js

```
define(
[
    'jquery'
],
function ($) {
    'use strict';

    return function (target) {
        $.widget('mage.configurable', target, {

            _displayTierPriceBlock: function (optionId) {
               //Do no thing here.
            }
        });

        return $.mage.configurable;
    };
});
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. Just making a few other changes and then I'll try this out. It may or may not be the 'best' way, but it is certainly a much cleaner solution than I have seen mentioned elsewhere. Will get back to you soon!

Comment: Where do I actually put the `requirejs-config.js` file inside app/design/frontend/[Vendor]/[Module]/... ?

Or is this a solution for 1.9?

Comment: This solution is for Magento 2. If having already a custom theme, put it under `app/design/frontend/[Vendor]/[Theme_name]/requirejs-config.js`.

Comment: I have found an alternative solution and answered the question myself. Can you see any problems with my own method?

Comment: Good to know you resolve your issue.

Comment: Thanks. I did give your answer a +1 by the way, but don't have enough rep on the magento stack for it to display yet.

Comment: @JoshuaFlood no worries.

Answer (score 1):

on magento 2.3.0 you can remove by editing

Magento_Catalog/templates/product/price/final_price.phtml

I added text to tell there is % when buy more 'by more and get %'
then I marked out the render of tier price.
So, no tier price is shown, only some replace text with link to product page where tier prices are correct.

`<a href="<?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ $block->getSaleableItem()->getProductUrl() ?>" class="minimal-price-link"> By more and get % 
<!-- marke out code or delete line
<?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ $block->renderAmountMinimal() ?> 
--> </a>`

Comment: Thanks goodlook. I've added this method to the answer and given you an upvote.